# MYSQL - Ejercicio "Sucursales que cuenten con autos de todos los tipos"

Tags: mysql, division

Considere el siguiente modelo relacional y resuelva las siguientes consultas en SQL.

Automovil(**autoID**, fabricante, modelo, cantPuertas, tipoAutoID, sucursalID)

TipoAuto(**tipoAutoID**, Tipo)

Sucursal(**sucursalID**, dirección, ciudad, pais)

Referencia: Los atributos en negrita son llaves primarias.

El ejercicio dice: Sucursales que cuenten con autos de *todos* los tipos.

En mi teoria tengo un operador que resulta ser muy útil pero no he encontrado manera de programarlo en MYSQL, he intentando alternativas de simular su comportamiento pero o bien termino en Empty Set o devuelve toda la columa de sucursales.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve probando con las siguientes consultas:

```
select sucursalID 
from sucursal 
where sucursalID in 
(
    select tipo 
    from sucursal 
    natural join automovil 
    natural join tipoAuto 
    group by sucursalID
);
```

Y

```
select sucursalID 
from sucursal 
where sucursalID in 
(
    select sucursalID 
    from sucursal 
    natural join automovil 
    natural join tipoAuto
)
group by sucursalID;
```

Estoy seguro que debo usar el group by en algún lado para hacer la distinción de sucursales, pero no logre comprender donde debería hacerlo.

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que llevas al momento

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Entendido! Soy nuevo en la comunidad y todavia me falta aprender mucho.
Agradezco sus comentarios! Ahi agregue unas consultas que estuve probando sin éxito.

Comment: Hola @JavierTierno además de lo que has hecho, por favor, agrega como están definidas las tablas y los datos que usaste de ejemplo

Comment: en realidad no tenes que usar join (no piden nada de la sucursal, o sea que con el id solo alcanza).. lo que si, tenes que usar [all](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/all-subqueries.html)... (y sobre esa algebra sobre tablas no entiendo nada)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando hagas un **JOIN** procura asignarle un *Alias* a cada una de las tablas que integran el join, esto lo hace mucho más fácil de leer & de identificar, también sirve cuando se tienen columnas con el mismo nombre. A su vez esto funciona a la hora de agruparlos, tal como quieres hacer con el **GROUP BY**

Te dejo un ejemplo bastante sencillo pero claro

```
SELECT *
FROM Sucursal AS suc
INNER JOIN Automovil AS aut ON (suc.sucursalID = aut.sucursalID)
WHERE suc.ciudad = "Rosario"
GROUP BY suc.sucursalID;
```